# raid 0+1, raid 3 or raid 1x2

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, raid, linux

I've a dell r210-II server with 4 x 300 Gb 10K SAS disks.

I want to use this server as Apache, mysql and mail server.

I think i'll switch a cluster system for mysql after 6 months.

I dont want to get any problem when i'll switch a clustered mysql service.

Which is the better configuration for this situation?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your actual question uses the wrong terminology but either way I'd suggest you use RAID 10, which is a level that uses all 4 disks as one large array, you'll have 600GB of usable space but the performance and resilience is great for such a small array.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use RAID 0+1 if 1+0 is an option. RAID 3 is a non-standard level, I don't think you can even find a controller that supports it, and 2 separate RAID 1s might be an option, but I don't see a reason to not use RAID 1+0.

Comment: Yes I'll use raid 10.. I think it's better for performance and safety.